# probability models

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The sales person of a pharmacy near a children’s hospital notices on one morning that
there are only 10 bottles of syrup A left. He knows that approximately 1 in 5 prescriptions
require syrup A. What is the probability that he will be able fill at least 30 prescriptions
before he gets a new stock of syrup A? (Assume that all other drugs are available).

Comment: See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: I would approach this as a negative binomial with the number of failures $r=10$ before the "experiment" is stopped, and the probability of success (not needing syrup A) as $p=4/5.$

Comment: Show the work you have done so far, and you may get a more detailed answer.